# Consolidate structure with xsl

Tags: xslt

Can this be done in XLST V2.0

I have an output from an editor that delivers tagged text in mixed order. And I need to consolidate it.

given the HTML

```html
  source:
 <para1>
  <para2>
     <em>emphazised <bold>bolded and emphazised</bold></em>
  </para2>
  <para2>
    <bold><em>bolded and emphazised</em></bold>
  </para2>
 </para1>
 
 target:
  <para1>
  <em>
  <para2>
     emphazised <bold>bolded and emphazised</bold>
  </para2>
  <para2>
    <bold>bolded and emphazised</bold>
  </para2>
  </em>
 </para1>

However theese source combination can occur as well but they cannot 
be consolidated as they are mixed within<para1> as not all text is emphazised, bolded or both:

  <para1>
  <para2>
    normal text <em>emphazised</em> <bold>bolded<em> and emphazised</em></bold>
  </para2>
  <para2>
    <bold>bolded<em> and emphazised</em></bold>
  </para2>
 </para1>
 
 <para1>
 <em><bold>
 <para2>
  normal text but emphazied and bolded from para1
  </para2>
  <para2>
   normal text but emphazied and bolded from para1
  </para2>
</em></bold>
 </para1>
```

`<em>` and `<bold>` tags can appear in any order inside each other 
`<em>` and `<bold>` can appear both a `<para1>` and `<para2>` level

Can it then be determined:
for each `<para1>` is there any text that is not in an `<em>` tag or `<bold>` tag.
for each `<para1>` is there any text that is not in both `<em>` tag and `<bold>` tag

and similar question for each `<para2>` ?

The purpose os to be able to fuse content with the same tags into a smaller number of tags and if all para2 tags are alike than move the the tags to para1 level. as the output may have many similar tagged text depending og how it was made.

Is this possible or would it require that the  and  tags always appears in the same order?

Comment: It  might be better if you first fix the sample you have posted to be well-formed XML (`<para2/>` is an empty element, not an end tag, that would be `</para2>`) and then show us the result you want to create for that sample you have posted.

Comment: allright edited the examples

Comment: You say the input is HTML but I don't think there are any `para1` or `para2` elements in HTML. And `em` in HTML would be an inline element that belongs inside of a block element like `div` or `p`, it would not make sense in HTML to transform a `<p><em>foo</em></p><p><em>bar</em></p>` to `<em><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></em>` as that is not a valid structure and any error correcting HTML parser in browsers would recorrect the structure when encountering it.

Comment: Hi true enough it is not pure HTML, but that is what I get from the source which is a GWT component. I translate it further to another format that cannot understand the <em> <bold> and similar HTML tags. The target format needs the information consolidated in para tags. So still the question remains around the principle problem, can XSLT be used in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly check such a condition in XSLT/XPath, for instance `para1[every $t in descendant::text()[normalize-space()] satisfies ($t/parent::em or $t/../parent::em)]` would check that any non-whitespace text node descendant of `para1` has an `em` parent or grandparent. Based on that you could write code like

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para1[every $t in descendant::text()[normalize-space()] satisfies ($t/parent::em or $t/../parent::em)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <em>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="strip"/>
            </em>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="em" mode="strip">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

that transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <para1>
  <para2>
     <em>emphazised <bold>bolded and emphazised</bold></em>
  </para2>
  <para2>
    <bold><em>bolded and emphazised</em></bold>
  </para2>
 </para1>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><para1><em>
  <para2>
     emphazised <bold>bolded and emphazised</bold>
  </para2>
  <para2>
    <bold>bolded and emphazised</bold>
  </para2>
 </em></para1>
```

and leaves

```
 <para1>
  <para2>
    normal text <em>emphazised</em> <bold>bolded<em> and emphazised</em></bold>
  </para2>
  <para2>
    <bold>bolded<em> and emphazised</em></bold>
  </para2>
 </para1>
```

unchanged. Of course it becomes more difficult handling various elements like `em` or `bold` at the same time.